# Thread run a "step" for each call C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

i have my main code executed from **MainWindow.xaml.cs** and a thread, called **testThread**.

I need testThread to read inside a folder (with subfolders too) decided by MainWindow and read one file per time, everytime MainWindow needs it. I know that using a thread is pretty useless with this example but i need this mechanic to be implemented in a bigger context.

What can be the best approach to realize this? My tought was to use a semaphore and lock the thread after every file read so i can unlock it everytime i need next file. Here what i tried to implement (and doesn't work):

**MainWindow.cs**

```
public static string myRootDir;

private void Button_test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        myRootDir = @"C:\";

        testThread myThread = new testThread();
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(myThread.start);
        workerThread.Start();

            //for this test i'm getting the first 10 files
        for (int c1 = 1; c1 < 10; c1++ )
        {
            result.Text += myThread.getNext();
            //this is just a test, so i wait 1 second from each request
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        result.Text = error.Message;
    }
}
```

**testThread.cs**

```
public class testThread
{
    private string rootDir = "";
    public static string currentFilePath = "";
    Semaphore mySemaphore = new Semaphore(0, 2);

    public void start()
    {
        rootDir = MainWindow.myRootDir;
        startReading(rootDir);
    }

    public string getNext()
    {
        mySemaphore.Release();
        return currentFilePath;
    }

    private void startReading(string root)
    {
        //read all the files in current dir
        foreach (string singleFilePath in Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.*"))
        {
            currentFilePath = singleFilePath;
            mySemaphore.WaitOne();
        }
        //repeat for all subfolders
        foreach (string singleDirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(root))
        {
            startReading(singleDirPath);
        }
    }
}
```

From debug i can see the code doesn't stop on `mySemaphore.WaitOne();`, and i suspect i'm doing other errors too!

Comment: check out C#'s `yield` statement.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the exact point of what you are intending to do. Bear in mind that the reason for using multi-threading is allowing different tasks to be run in parallel; but if you need the results from the previous tasks as inputs for the next one, what would be the point of using multiple threads?

Comment: thank you for your comments, i'm checking out what yield is. In this program multithreading is useless i know, but its part of a big context that requires use of at least one extra thread, i'm forced to do this :(

Comment: But perhaps you should explain a situation closer to the real one in order to get proper help. If you have to start/stop the threads on a regular basis, the resulting performance wouldn't be too good and it might even be better to rely on an alternative approach (avoiding multiple threads).

Comment: thank you for your interest, i need to do this because while scanning my application needs to be responsive. Scanning a single file is kinda a quick operation, but i need to do some slow operation on every file so with a single threaded application this is going to freeze all the UI while users needs to do other stuff!

Comment: ok i got what yield is, pretty cool! But it doesn't fit my needs, everytime my thread do one scan it do a single yield return, but i need to trigger a return from MainWindow and not from the thread itself! Thank you anyway @Dan-o :)

Comment: From your description, it does seem that multi-threading is required (will not be too efficient but there is no other way). A simple backgroundworker implementation should take care of what you want easily. You might either start a new bgw for each document and rely on the RunWorkerCompleted event or call the bgw once for all the documents and use the ProgressChanged event by calling ReportProgress when required.